# Cambiar color ProgressBar

Tags: android, progressbar

queria saber como cambiar el color del progreso de un ProgressBar circular ( no el que es una barra)

el codigo de mi progress bar

> android:id="@+id/pg_bar"

```
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

define la propiedad  `android:background`, que en este caso no funciona como `background` del `ProgressBar` si no como el color del elemento:

```
 android:background ="@drawable/mipbstyle"
```

dentro de tu folder /drawable (dentro de /res) crea el archivo que define el background y contiene tu color personalizado `mipbstyle.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="9" android:useLevel="false">    
        <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#001100" 
            android:endColor="#00FF00"
            android:angle="0"/>
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Modificando un poco tu progressBar quedaría como:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pg_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:max="500"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mipbstyle" />
```

o programaticamente mediante:

```
 myProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable()
    .setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

en ambos casos obtendrías algo similar a :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si defino el background, se me cambia el fondo de la progressbar, lo que necesito es que cambie el color de la barra de progreso ( la que se mueve en circulos) no el fondo

Comment: Hey Nicolas, en este caso el "background" funciona diferente, agregaré una imagen de como se mostraría en ambos casos. De hecho edité tu ProgressBar también. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias !

Comment: Que bien que lo solucionaste! =) saludos!

Comment: Elena sos mi salvacion desde hace unos meses!

Answer (score 0):

Aquí comentan como cambiarlo por código [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928926/6118054)
me imagino que es lo que pides.

```
ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar(
                context,
                null,
                android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: no me sirve ese ejemplo- Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

En tu xml

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CustomProgressBar" 
    android:layout_margin="5dip" />
```

Y en res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources> 
    <style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
      <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
    </style>       
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
```

Y custom_progress_bar_horizontal es un XML almacenados en la carpeta estirable que define la barra de progreso personalizada.
Espero que esto le ayudará.

Answer (score 0):

estuvo bien lo que hiciste pero te equivocaste al mandar a llamar al diseño de tu progressbar. La verdad me ayudo, gracias
este es mi codigo

```
   <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progresbar_cargando"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:max="500"
            android:progress="0"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progres_personalizado"
            ></ProgressBar>
```