# ¿ Cómo cambiar color a ProgressBar?

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente código en el .xml, ¿ cómo hago para ponerla roja o amarilla o cambiar el tipo de barra? La que tengo es la azul básica de android...

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />
```

Comment: Mirate http://www.materialdoc.es/linear-progress/ pero solo funciona en Android L para adelante.

Comment: [Aqui](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14196/cambiar-color-progressbar) tienes una pregunta muy similar, tal vez te sirvan las respuestas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplemente define el color mediante **[setColorFilter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter))**, un ejemplo usando [getIndeterminateDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getIndeterminateDrawable()) para crear un progressBar en modo inderterminado:

```
 myProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

o usando [getProgressDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgressDrawable()) para crear un progressBar en modo progresivo:

```
 myProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

con esto tendrías como resultado el color esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si, perfecto muchas gracias, vi la misma ayer ! :) +1 elena

Comment: @RfMvs ¿sabías que si **aceptás una respuesta** (haciendo click en el tilde a la izquierda de la misma) ganás 2 puntos de reputación? Más información en [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haria asi:

```
ProgressBar miprogressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb_default);
miprogressbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```